# Acess 2007 one-to-many relationship counting

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

My Set-up: I have two tables: tblAuthors and tblBooks. tblAuthors includes a list authors: Kurt Vonnegut, Frank Herbert, J. K. Rowling, John Nichols, etc.. tblBooks includes a list of books: Slaughter House Five, Cat's Craddle, Monkey House, Dune, Harry Potter, Milagro Beanfield War, etc..

There is a one-to-many relationship between tblBooks and tblAuthors; Authors in tblAuthors is used as the primary key for this relationship. tblAuthors has a *Number of Books* coloumn which tells the user of the table how many books each author has written that is included in the table. Currently the user (sadly me) must input this information by hand, updating it after every book is entered and given an author. Although this is not particularly difficult because I can simply see how many books are related to the author in tblAuthors because of the relationship, it is sometimes difficult to remember to update it (not to mention a colossal pain in the butt).

**I want *Number of Books* to update automatically as I add more books.** If there is a code out there please let me know!!

I am not really familiar with VBA and could use an explanation that is geared towards someone who may not understand all of the facets of the code.

Thank you in advance for any help that you give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to read [about relational database design](http://r937.com/relational.html) It is not usual to store calculated fields because the information can easily be obtained from a query.

```
SELECT AuthorID, 
       Count(BookID) 
FROM Books
GROUP BY AuthorID
```

Comment: Hey Remou, I was wondering if you would be able to help me a bit furhter. I got the query to work matching up the number of books to the author. Now how do I get this infomation into my preexisting table? I have attempted to use the 'Make table', 'Append', and 'Update' actions to try and get the information into tblAuthors, but to no avail. I am brand new at sql and fairly new to access, any help would be outstanding!

Comment: His point was you do not want to store that information in the Authors table. Any time you need the number of books, you run a query to retrieve it. If you need the Authors name along with the number of books, you can use a join: `SELECT tblAuthors.Name, COUNT(tblBooks.BookID) as NumberOfBooks FROM tblAuthors INNER JOIN tblBooks ON tblAuthors.AuthorID = tblBooks.AuthorID`

Comment: +1 Dynamic information should be determined on the fly using a query such as this.

Comment: @Ethan'sLackey `Now how do I get this infomation into my preexisting table` No, you calculate it on the fly using a query. You shouldn't keep a "Book Count" field in `tblAuthors` because it is always changing.

Comment: I understand that you should just be updating this on the 'fly'. However, just knowing how many there are isn't my end goal. I am using 'Book Count' in my report generation drawing from my tables. I want to be able to have the number of books written by the author show up in my report. I also want this number to automatically update so that this database will be very user friendly. As the user inputs a new book (connecting it to the author) I want it to update 'Book Count' to be current. I don't nessicarily need this value to update in my table, but I do need it to update in the form.

Comment: Thank you for all of the wonderful feedback so far. You guys have been a great help!!

Comment: There are so many ways of doing what you want without updating the table with a number that will always be out of date, it is hard to know where to start.

Comment: For your report, you can link to the count query. You will need to learn how to link tables if you wish to continue with MS Access. For your form, you can use DCount in a textbox `=DCount("BookID","BookTable","AuthorID=" & txtAuthorID)`

Comment: There is a general "rule" - get the database design right, then worry about presenting the data.